# Does irrotational + incompressible imply homogeneity?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I've been struggling to understand something in a paper I'm reading [(this one)](http://lcd-www.colorado.edu/%7Eaxbr9098/teach/ASTR_5410/material/KdVDeriv.pdf). The paper assumes incompressibility and irrotationality and follows that $\nabla \rho=0$ and $\partial _t \rho=0$, so it's basically saying that the flow is homogeneous as well. I get that $\partial _t \rho + \vec u \cdot (\nabla \rho)=0$, as this follows from the continuity equation. But apart from that I'm quite lost... or did they implicitly assume it somewhere?

Comment: I think by "incompressible" here the authors mean that $\rho$ is a constant. So I believe those two equations do not follow from the assumptions, they are the assumption itself.

Comment: PS I guess you take $\nabla\cdot\vec{v}=0$ as the definition of incompressible (makes sense...). I do not think zero-divergence flow impies $\rho$ is homogeneous... you can very easily find counterexamples, for instance an arbitrary density profile moving at constant speed, irrotational, zero-divergence... but not constant.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback, your counterexample definitely makes sense!